# date time now format

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, string-formatting

How do I get only day+month+year in C#?

Comment: I need only the question. Putting a ? mark at the end of a statement does not a question make.

Answer (score 7):

Vague question.

Do you need this as a string?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

There are also Day, Month, Year values you can work with on the DateTime struct.

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need is right here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx